# how to return a reference to a default value of a non-type template argument

Tags: c++

I have done a lot of research on this but I wasn't able to find a design pattern addressing the problem. This is a minimal description of what I'm trying to perform.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, T default_value=T{}>
class A{
private:
       T inclassValue;
public:
       A(T icv):inclassValue{icv}{}       

       const T& operator[](int k){
          if(k==1) return inclassValue;
       return default_value; 
       }
};

struct two_int{int x;int y;};

int main(){
    A<int> a{4};
    cout << "a[0]=" << a[0] << endl;
    cout << "a[1]=" << a[1] << endl;
    /*
    A<two_int> b{{3,5}};
    cout << "b[0]=" << b[0].x << "," << b[0].y  << endl;
    cout << "b[1]=" << b[1].x << "," << b[1].y  << endl;
    */
    return 0;

}
```

The code will compile, link and output as expected

```
a[0]=0
a[1]=4
```

The compiler complains though and issues a warning for the line of code where default_value is used

```
return default_value;//Returning reference to local temporary object
```

which makes some sense. Uncommenting the last part in main and compiling, the compiler issue this time an error while building the template

```
template <class T,  const T default_value= T{}>//A non-type template parameter cannot have type 'two_int'
```

while what I ideally hope for is

```
b[0]=0,0
b[1]=3,5
```

I was able to come up with a solution by adding an extra helper class, that will provide the default_value of T (as a static member), to the template arguments. I'm not convinced by the robustness of my trick and I was wondering if there exists a design pattern addressing this. The warning for types and the error for non-types. Also, I shall add that my primary goal is to be able to provide default_value at will (6 for int for example instead of 0).

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it, with A<int> b{{3,5}}; you pass two arguments to the constructor, but it only takes one, a T, which you've specified to be <int>. So the template type of T is int, and then you create an A by passing two arguments to it when it only wants one.

Comment: I believe the problem here is the the first template argument T is a type, and then the second template argument is an instance of T you initialised with T{ }. T have to be the same the thing but in the first argument it's a type and in the second argument it's a non-type, it's an object. Though I'm not sure about this.

Comment: It was a typo. I meant to write two_int which I corrected now. I use {3,5} for list initializing the two_int class member of A.

Comment: Are you using c++17?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.2, Apple LLVM 9.0 and the settings shows C++ language dialect as GNU++14. But I can change it to C++17!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for, but perhaps a static helper finishing for creating a static default T could be useful:

```
template <typename T>
static const T& default_value() {
  static const T* t = new T{};
  return *t;
}
```

Note this will construct T at most once even across threads (in c++11), but still never destruct T. Since it's static, it's likely the lack of destruction is acceptable, but this of course depends on T.

Comment: Why `new`? Is there a reason for dynamic allocation?

Comment: Right. So we could have just made a `static const T` on the stack and returned a reference to that and be done. But given that T may not be trivially destructible, there could be a dependency on the order of the destruction of T and some other static constant. Since the order of destruction of static objects is not well defined between compilation units, it's often a good idea to either manually clean up static resources from main and/or not invoke their destructors.

Comment: I'm essentially referencing ideas presented here about static destruction: https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Static_and_Global_Variables

Comment: The message I got when compiling his code is similar to his: 'two_int': illegal type for non-type template parameter 'default_value'. I'm interested in knowing if this is valid syntax or what.

Comment: In all honesty, I was addressing removing the warning about reference of a temporary. This doesn't address the use of constructor arguments and template types in the second part of his question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one version that forwards arguments to the constructor of a default_value stored as `constexpr`. You are quite limited here as to what is valid to pass as arguments (not sure exactly how limited) so it will depend on your use-case.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, auto... Args>
class A{
private:
       T inclassValue;
       constexpr static T default_val = T{Args...}; // Changed to curly brackets here
public:
       constexpr A(T icv):inclassValue{icv}{}       

       const T& operator[](int k){
          if(k==1) return inclassValue;
       return default_val; 
       }
};

struct two_int{int x;int y;};

int main(){
    A<int> a{4};
    cout << "a[0]=" << a[0] << endl;
    cout << "a[1]=" << a[1] << endl;

    A<two_int> b{{3,5}};
    cout << "b[0]=" << b[0].x << "," << b[0].y  << endl;
    cout << "b[1]=" << b[1].x << "," << b[1].y  << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, now A<int,6> makes 6 the default_value.

Comment: With `{}` in the initializer of `default_value` you can do `A<two_int, 2, 4>` aswell. Still no way to pass floats or doubles though.